# Determine $x$ for which series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

We are given a series:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \Bigg|\frac{x^n}{n(\log n)^2}\Bigg|
$$
We need to find the possible values of $x$ for which the series converges.

I tried to use the Ratio Test but ended up getting
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(x)\Bigg(\frac{2\log n + (\log n)^2}{2\log(n+1)+\big(\log(n+1)\big)^2}\Bigg)
$$

How to proceed?

Comment: Hint: try comparing the series to Harmonic-like series. For $|x| \leq 1$ you can prove that the series is smaller than something convergent and for $|x| > 1$ you can prove that is is larger than something divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|x|\le 1,$ the $n$th term is bounded above by $\frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}.$ Since $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n}$ converges (by the integral test for example), our series converges for $|x|\le 1.$ For $|x| > 1,$ the $n$th term is bounded below by $\frac{|x|^n}{n^3}$ for large $n.$ The ratio test shows $\sum \frac{|x|^n}{n^3}$ diverges for $|x| > 1,$ hence our series diverges for $|x|>1$ by the comparison test.‌

Answer (score 3):

The ratio $\dfrac n{n+1}$ tends to $1$. A little less obviously, $\dfrac{\log^2n}{\log^2(n+1)}$ also tends to $1$ because

$$\log n<\log(n+1)<\log(n)+1.$$

So the series converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$. For $|x|=1$, you need deeper analysis.

---

For $x=1$, consider the terms of rank between $2^{n}$ and $2^{n+1}$ (excluded). They are each bounded above by $n^{-2}2^{-n}$ and there are $2^{n-1}$ of them, for a total bounded by $n^{-2}/2$. Hence by this grouping, the series converges together with the Basel series.

Comment: @KaranKaran What inequality can't you understand ? This is elementary.

Comment: Also, for $x=1$: "Bertrand series" may be a useful keyword.

Comment: After your edit: for $x=1$, the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$ is *convergent*.

Comment: (If you don't know or don't want to use the result about Bertrand series: $$\int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x} = \int_1^\infty \frac{du}{u^2}$$from the change of variable "$u=\ln x$")

Comment: @ClementC.: oooops, right, fixing.

Comment: For $|x|=1$, you can apply *Dirichlet's test* (I suppose $x$ is a complex variable here?).

Comment: Your original (deleted) analysis of the case $x=1$ was flawed because you should have  summed over onlythose $ n$ that are  perfect squares, else you have multiple counting. E.g. the set of integers between $2^{-1+\sqrt {10}}$ and $2^{\sqrt {10}}$ overlaps the set of integers between $2^{-1+\sqrt {11}}$ and $2^{\sqrt {11}}$.... The Cauchy condensation test shows that $\sum_nn^{-1}(\log n)^{-2}$ converges

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I fixed my post since. But there was no overlap, as the mention "excluded" was meant to say.

Comment: Your amendment (edit) came at about the time I was typing my comment. Your A is fine now. At first I couldn't explain the flaw in your original.  I think your original would make a cool example  of an "explain the apparent paradox" type of exercise /:) .............+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I agree with you. there was something wrong in the handling of $\sqrt n$.